# What happens to the return value of printf()?

Tags: c

I recently learnt that printf() returns the number of characters it is called to print. But I was wondering I never "used" this return value before, like:

```
int c = printf("Called func\n");
```

or

```
printf("%d", printf("Called func\n"));
```

I simply wrote statements where the function of printf was performed like:

```
printf("Called func\n");
```

So what "happened" to the return value of printf()? How does the compiler know its "ok" to not use the returned integer?

Comment: "*How does the compiler know its "ok" to not use the returned integer?*" you told it by coding `printf( ...);`.

Comment: @alk Why doesn't the compiler throw an error, since I called the function "wrongly"?

Comment: From the formal language perspective it's not wrong to call a function and ignore the value it "returns", it evaluates to. Please see [Basile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48050046/694576) below.

Comment: Any simple expression is a valid statement. Calling a function with return value is an expression. Just the same as writing `5;` or `(strcmp);` The compiler might issue some warning aboud expression without sideffect or similar, but it is perfectly OK to ignore any expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [expression-statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements) like

```
 printf("x=%d\n", x);
```

is similar to

```
(void) printf("x=%d\n", x);
```

the value given by [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is computed (number of characters successfully output, or -1 on error), then discarded and ignored.

BTW, it is the same for an assignment like `x=5;` : the value (5) of that assignment expression `x=5` is discarded and ignored; of course its side-effect is done, of changing the value in the location for variable `x`. If you coded `printf("x=%d\n", (x=5))` the value of that assignment would be used and passed to `printf`.

An [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) might (or not) generate slightly different [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) (see [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule), at least for C++). But the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) language specification (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) defines in English wording the observable behavior of your program, i.e. its [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

Notice that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (and some other compilers, e.g. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)), provides, as an extension, the ability to declare a function with the `warn_unused_result` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html). You'll then get a warning if the result of that function is not explicitly used.

Notice that some programming languages (Ocaml, Scheme, Haskell, ....) don't have statements, and everything there is an expression, some of them having a side-effect.

Comment: Why do you say the value (5) of the statement `x=5;` is discarded and ignored? Isn't the value (5) stored in the memory location intended to be the variable `x`? How is it discarded? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: It is stored, and 5 is the value of the `x=5` expression, whose important side-effect is to change the value inside the location of variable `x`

Comment: @Truth-seek: You could have done `y = (x = 5) + 1;` which would have set `y` to `6`.

Comment: @alk Thanks. So much insight is ignored where they teach me